# connecting arduino to industrial motor controller through RS232

Tags: arduino, motor, rs232

I need to interface with a motor controller through RS232. I am using an arduino for this. The datasheet has a page on RS232 interfacing shown below, could someone please identify what I would need to communicate with this from an arduino?

[image: serial datasheet page]

there are no details on the RS232 voltages, as far as I know following the standard I should be able to communicate with lines from 0 to +3.3v since this lies within the spec of 0v to +3 - +12v however so far I am unable to get a response from the device by connecting Tx, Rx, and GND to a ttl logic USB serial device, nor my arduino.

Using the RS232 cable supplied with the controller I am able to communicate both with the supplied software and through a serial COM port sniffer, so I am sure my data addressing is correct.

I feel like there is a perhaps a voltage level difference issue, or maybe i need to control the other pins however I was under the impression these were optional, could someone please shed some light?

Cheers

Comment: RS-232 requires an inverting level shifter, connection without that will damage your Arduino.  Ironically the oldest Arduinos had that an a 9-pin connector, with the USB being a subsequent replacement.

Comment: check your DC static levels for idle to confirm active and correct polarity and note jumper between pins 5,7

Answer (score 1):

A TTL to RS232 shield is one solution

https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13029. Details in DOC links  will give more clues.